# filtering xpath with same functionality on different pages

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Because I have the same functionality on several different pages and dont want to repeat myself. I want to make a xpath that retrieves the element with a wildcard. On each page I have a input ID, they look like this:

```
tbAAFound_fileUpload
tbBBFound_fileUpload
tbCCFound_fileUpload
tbDDFound_fileUpload
tbEEFound_fileUpload
```

I want to make the xpath filter so that it searches if it can find the element on more than one page.

When I try the following xpath:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[starts-with(@id, 'tb:') and contains(@id, '_fileUpload')]")]
private IWebElement UrlFileElement { get; set; }
```

Selenium cannot find the element. Hope that you guys can help me out.

Comment: `starts-with(@id, 'tb')`, not `starts-with(@id, 'tb:')`. Note the `:`.

Comment: It worked for the first page, but on the other pages it cannot seem to find the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`starts-with(@id, 'tb:')` remove `:` , as it's not in id actually

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[contains(@id,’_fileUpload’)]")]
private IWebElement UrlFileElement { get; set; }
```